# Update inputText in jsf without ajax

Tags: jsf

I have 2 fields: inputText and selectOneMenu.
How I can updated value of inputText without ajax, when value selectOneMenu is changed?
I use

```
valueChangeListener="myMetod()"
 onchange="submit()"
```

for selectOneMenu. But when submit() is called, in inputText metod setValue for inputText is called. And I get old value

Comment: update your question with `valueChangeListner` method code which would help to debug your problem.

Comment: So you want to refresh the page when changing the value of `<h:selectOneMenu>` instead of ajax behavior? Is this your functional requirement?